# How to stress test my page

Tags: performance, load, performance-testing, stress-testing

I would like to test my web app under high load.

What I'd need to do is.
Load the page => click the button => fill the form => click the button.

I'd need to do this to simulate 5-10k page requests, which is expected to happen after we launch one service (based on previous years data as there's going to be some big pre-sale discount for only a couple of items)

What service or approach would be the most suitable to do this?

Comment: Considering this is an eCommerce application, first qualify the financial risk that is on the line for a failed launch.  Now that this is known, go to the market of service providers who can provide both labor and tools for a performance test as a service to test to your defined model.   This is the least risky path considering revenue is on the line for this event.  Don't fool around and make this your first performance testing event as it will not end well and will actually increase your risk rather than decrease it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use services such as SoapUI or Loader.IO. Both are supposed to be free if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Gatling.io is another good tool you can use for this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of free and open source load testing tools you can consider listed at http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview

Given your requirement of 5-10k concurrent requests my expectation is that you need the tool which can be run in ["clustered"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) mode as you might hit the resource limit of a single load generator so you can use several machines running the load testing tool so it can be done in distributed manner.

One more factor would be possibility to record and replay the scenario so you could just run your steps in browser and the load testing tool would capture the relevant requests so you will be able to replay them with increased number of users.

Check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) for example evaluation and research. Once you stick to this or that tool you can ask questions regarding your scenario implementation using a specific [StackOverflow tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: http://www.opensourcetesting.org/ doesn't work anymore.